# Проблема с областью видимости массива

Tags: c++, ооп

У меня есть вектор в мейне, как передать его в класс? На пример в классе есть ссылка, то нужно присвоить этот класс ссылке или указателю. У меня почему что в классе не видно моего массива.

```cpp
class Builder {
  shared_ptr<Unit> Sarr = arr;
  public: virtual void addWizard() = 0;
  virtual void addWorker() = 0;
  virtual void addWarrior() = 0;
  virtual void CreatGroup() = 0;
};

int main() {
  srand(time(0));
  vector<shared_ptr<Unit>> arr;
  system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код, пожалуйста

Comment: `
int main() {
 srand(time(0));

 vector<shared_ptr<Unit>>arr;
 

 system("pause");
}`

Comment: `код`
class Builder
{
 
 shared_ptr<Unit>Sarr=arr;
  
public:
 virtual void addWizard() = 0;
 virtual void addWorker() = 0;
 virtual void addWarrior() = 0;
 virtual void CreatGroup()=0;
 
};

Comment: У вас нигде нет ни массивов, ни ссылок. Инициализацию полей класса осуществляйте в конструкторе.

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит разобраться что такое "класс" и "объект класса"

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте себя на место компилятора. Вы читаете описание класса, натыкаетесь на какое-то `arr`, которое нигде жо этого не встречалось... Что ему делать?

Более того, это `arr` - *локальная переменная* в `main`. А представим, что перед `main` у вас строка -

```
Builder b;
```

Да, я знаю, что это абстрактный класс... но представим на минуту, что он не абстрактный - как ему этот `arr` получить, которого и на свете-то нет?

Нет уж, будьте любезны соблюдать правила видимости... типа

```
class Builder {
  public:
    Builder(const shared_ptr<Unit>& arr):Sarr(arr){}
    shared_ptr<Unit> Sarr;
```

и после этого передавайте тот `arr`, который нужен и там, где он существует...